# activeadmin link_to

Tags: admin, link-to

Hello i have to make some links in the Active Admin admin pages, but i have some problems understanding the hashes to make searches for specific entries, for example:

```
column 'Campaigns' do |advertiser|
  link_to "#{advertiser.campaigns.count} campaigns", admin_campaigns_path('q[advertiser_id_eq]' => advertiser.id)
end
```

I dont understand the meaning of:

```
('q[advertiser_id_eq]')
```

Why is it inside a "q[]" and has a "_eq?"

or:

```
column 'Entrants' do |campaign|
      link_to "#{campaign.entrants.count} entrants", admin_entrants_path('q[by_campaign_id]' => campaign.id)
end
```

When i click the links they make a search for the linked information in the relation at the models but when i change it for a normal:

```
('[campaign_id]' => campaign.id)
```

it just sends me to the normal index of all the "campaigns" in this last case. the documentation for activeadmin dont realy say much about how the searches work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active admin uses meta search gem to search results. Try using
q[by_campaign_id] => "#{campaign.id}"

Answer (score -1):

```
'q[advertiser_id_eq]' => advertiser.id
'q[by_campaign_id]' => campaign.id
```

these two don't work in my code, it just shows all the campaigns.
it should like

```
'q[advertiser_id_eq]' => "#{advertiser.id}"
```